# Cannot find symbol error in an if-else block

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out where I've gone wrong in my code, I keep receiving a "cannot find symbol" error in the first line and I can't seem to spot the fault. Here is the portion of my code. Help?!

```
if (Array.getlength(args) == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
        while (Text.thereAreMoreLinesIn(fileName))
        {
            String line = Text.readNextLineFrom((fileName));
            Text.splitAtSpaces(line);
            ICAO = Text.toDouble(args[i+0]);
            t = Text.toDouble(args[i+1]);
            v = Text.toDouble(args[i+2]);
            windChill = Weather.windChillNA(t,v);
            Map.setTemperature(args[i+0],windChill);
        } 
    }
}
else {System.out.print("Help");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code for easier viewing and error checking.

Comment: Please improve the clarity and completeness of your question. In its present form it's unanswerable.

Comment: Presumably, you want to be using `if(args.length == 0)`, instead of what you have now.

Comment: I think you should use `if (args.length != 0)`

Comment: The OP actually seems to be using `java.lang.reflect.Array`, and for no apparent reason. As it is, the for loop will only be reached if it doesn't iterate.

Answer (score 4):

It should be Array.getLength, not Array.getlength
Java is case sensitive, you should use an IDE like eclipse to get warnings about these kind of problems.

Other than that, your loop will not run, your if statement must be something like this

```
if (Array.getLength(args) > 0)
```

Comment: I dont think Id be able to use your suggestion. My if statement is supposed to be used when there are no command line arguments.

Comment: When there are no command line arguments, you won't be able to run this line: `t = Text.toDouble(args[i+1]);`

Comment: I understand that, but once my program detects there are no command line args, it is supposed to pull them out of "fileName"

Comment: @BenMorrison when you have no arguments, then args.length=0. Then, how can you iterate this for loop --> for (int i=0; i< args.length; i++)

Comment: IDK! ='( Im struggling.

Comment: It's like you would do `if(!x) {if(x) {..}}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is `if(args.length>0)` or `if(args.length!=0)`, since I can find no use of the `Array`. As already specified, with your current statement, even without the error, your loop wouldn't run.